# How do I use Python 3.8+ in AWS Sagemaker?

Tags: python-3.x, amazon-web-services, amazon-sagemaker

I am using a Sagemaker Notebook Instance and created custom kernels for Python 3.8 and 3.9. I can select these kernels in my Notebook, but when I run `sys.version`, it shows

`3.7.10 | packaged by conda-forge | (default, Feb 19 2021, 16:07:37)  [GCC 9.3.0]`.

Running `!python3 -V` shows `Python 3.7.12`.

How can I use Python 3.8?

EDIT:
I created my kernels using the instructions from https://awstip.com/how-to-use-a-newer-python-version-in-aws-sagemaker-notebook-1682a89625ef

This boils down to running these commands from the Terminal in Notebook Instance:

```
conda create -n  my_custom_python_39 python=3.9

source activate my_custom_python_39

pip install virtualenv  
virtualenv my_custom_python_39_venv 
conda deactivate

source my_custom_python_39_venv/bin/activate 
pip install ipykernel 
python -m ipykernel install --user --name=my_custom_python_39
```

Comment: "created custom kernels" exactly how? you have to provide step by step instructions allow for acurate reproduction of you setup and problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd recommend you go thorugh the AWS sample LCC script [here](https://github.com/aws-samples/amazon-sagemaker-notebook-instance-lifecycle-config-samples/tree/master/scripts/persistent-conda-ebs).

I combined those script and ran below commands from the Terminal of my Notebook instance and it created a custom Python 3.8 kernel.

```bash
WORKING_DIR=/home/ec2-user/SageMaker/custom-miniconda
mkdir -p "$WORKING_DIR"
wget https://repo.anaconda.com/miniconda/Miniconda3-4.6.14-Linux-x86_64.sh -O "$WORKING_DIR/miniconda.sh"
bash "$WORKING_DIR/miniconda.sh" -b -u -p "$WORKING_DIR/miniconda" 
rm -rf "$WORKING_DIR/miniconda.sh"


# Create a custom conda environment
source "$WORKING_DIR/miniconda/bin/activate"
KERNEL_NAME="custom_python"
PYTHON="3.8"

conda create --yes --name "$KERNEL_NAME" python="$PYTHON"
conda activate "$KERNEL_NAME"

pip install --quiet ipykernel

# Customize these lines as necessary to install the required packages
conda install --yes numpy
pip install --quiet boto3


source "$WORKING_DIR/miniconda/bin/activate"

for env in $WORKING_DIR/miniconda/envs/*; do
    BASENAME=$(basename "$env")
    source activate "$BASENAME"
    python -m ipykernel install --user --name "$BASENAME" --display-name "Custom ($BASENAME)"
done

# Optionally, uncomment these lines to disable SageMaker-provided Conda functionality.
# echo "c.EnvironmentKernelSpecManager.use_conda_directly = False" >> /home/ec2-user/.jupyter/jupyter_notebook_config.py
# rm /home/ec2-user/.condarc


echo "Restarting the Jupyter server.."
# restart command is dependent on current running Amazon Linux and JupyterLab
CURR_VERSION=$(cat /etc/os-release)
if [[ $CURR_VERSION == *$"http://aws.amazon.com/amazon-linux-ami/"* ]]; then
    sudo initctl restart jupyter-server --no-wait
else
    sudo systemctl --no-block restart jupyter-server.service
fi
```

Once the `jupyter-server` is restarted, you should see the new custom Kernel from the launcher:
[image: notebook launcher]

Opening a notebook using the custom Kernel gives me the following result:

```py
import sys
sys.version

'3.8.13 | packaged by conda-forge | (default, Mar 25 2022, 06:04:18) \n[GCC 10.3.0]'
```

Comment: I followed your answer and still get the older version when I issue "!python --version". Do you have any suggestions to get the python3.8 working? I can see the custom kernel under the notebook, however, when I open a notebook using it, I still get the older Python version.